Creating a custom PopupMenuItem
In order to encapsulate reusable custom functionality, I want to create a custom widget which can be used in place of PopupMenuItem.
The following works, but is not want I want:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarPopupMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarPopupMenuItem({super.key});

  @override
  PopupMenuItem<String> build(BuildContext context) {
    return const PopupMenuItem(
      value: '1',
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
            child: Text('icon'),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 50, child: Text('label'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This can be added to a List<PopupMenuItem<String>> as follows:
[
  const AppBarPopupMenuItem().build(context),
]

There are two issues:
First, I am expecting to be able to use my custom widget without explicitly calling the build() method, as follows:
[
  const AppBarPopupMenuItem(...),
]

Second, other custom widgets I have built or seen have the following signature:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

not
  @override
  PopupMenuItem<String> build(BuildContext context) {

When the signature returns a Widget, even when calling the build() method explicitly, it does not work.
Could anyone assist,
Thanks

in order to build a custom popupMenuItem, you need to copy all of its code and paste to a new file created by you. Then review the code and modify the code as you want. I also built a custom pop up menu by copying and pasting the code to my own file, then reviewed and modified it as I wanted. Now I have a cool dropdown widget)).
